# Cannot mount, partition, format brand new USB

Tags: ubuntu, usb, partitioning, usb-storage

I've recently bought a new TDK 4 GB USB stick, but when I try to mount it (I'm runnning Ubuntu 12.04, but neither in Windows 7/8.1 it works) in various ways Gparted, Disk Utility, simply pluggin it into usb port .. I receive this error : "unrecognised disk label".

Using "sudo parted /dev/sdc" it gives the exactly error .. and with GParted I've successfully managed to understand that no partition exists, and when attempting to create a new partition it does nothing.

Is it completely broken out, or have I any possibility to rescue this brand new USB?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take it back to where you bought it. No point trying to fix something you can probably get replaced for free.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Use Palimpsest Disk Utility to completely erase the drive whilst the drive is unmounted. Palimpsest has a mount / unmount button.

Step 2 - Reformat / partition the drive using Palimpsest.

Comment: sorry, do you mean the default disk utility in ubuntu? And, by the way, waht do you mean by "completely erase", format drive? If it's the case, it gives the error "Daemon is inhibited"

Comment: I mean precisely 'Palimpsest Disk Utility'. Open a Terminal and do `palimpsest` If you see 'command not found' then do `sudo apt-get install palimpsest` and then follow my original instructions.

Comment: same story .. "Daemon is inhibited"

Comment: More information = more help. Be more explicit, give us much detail as possible and I will do my best to help you. Are you saying that Palimpsest gave that error msg?

Comment: more details .. sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc -> Disk /dev/sdc: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes 124 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1018 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0xe4991204 Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: Ok. Have you tried Palimpsest? I have experienced similar in the past and have always found Palimpsest to be helpful.

Comment: yes! of course!